# How can I import JavaScript Math module using Nativescript framework?

Tags: nativescript

guys, I'm new at programming and I'm trying to use some Math properties in my app (I'm using Nativescript, which is pretty similar to React Native). However, there are some specific things that I can't do while using Nativescript that are really easy to do using vanilla JS. I'm talking about Math module. I mean, I just wanna use in my code something like "Math.sqrt(25)" to have "5", and things like that. In Nativescript, for example, I can use some modules by declaring variables. Example: if I want to use frame modules (that are specific from Nativescript), I just have to do this:

var frameModule = require("ui/frame");

But I can't do that with commonJS modules such as Math. Maybe I just don't know the path or something. Anyway, I'll bless anyone who can helps me, thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The Math library is part of your JavaScript and you can easily access it by just using **Math** in your code. You get an example:

```
var MathPiNumber = Math.PI;
console.log(MathPINumber); //You will get 3.1415926.....
```

If you want to know what else is *out-of-the-box* part of JS you can read it here:

[JavaScript Global Objects - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

For example you can also use **Date**  like in their example shown:

```
var date1 = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
console.log(date1) // Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Your title  question describes "How can I import JavaScript Math module using Nativescript framework?" My answer tries to explain that its part of the framework itself and u don't need to import. If i understood your question wrong - You could try to commend that i missunderstood and correct my understanding of your question. Hopefully there are just few people like you out there.